# What fromUser,toUser indiacate in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

when i am trying to under stand below Code Snippet stuck in function fromUser(text) {....}   start diving in internet found nothing. don't understand what it will do  .

```
app.directive('mobileNumberValidation', function ($parse) {
    return {

        require: "ngModel",
        restrict: "ECA",
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            function fromUser(text) {
                var limitLength = 19;
                if (text) {
                    if (text.length > limitLength) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue.substring(0, limitLength));
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    }
                    return text;
                }
                return undefined;
            }
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It wiil limit `ng-model` value to 19 symbols.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko  yes but " function fromUser(text) "  what this will do ?

Comment: You have its source right on your screen, I hope. It will limit model value length to 19 symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fromUser` is a function which is passed to `$parsers`, which eventually change the `formatting\value` of `input` tag on which this `directive` will be applied.
[Read this](https://alexperry.io/angularjs/2014/12/10/parsers-and-formatters-angular.html) and also see [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e83auqcw/)

In your case:

Lets say this directive is applied on some input like below :

```
<input mobileNumberValidation ng-model="user.number">
```

So `fromUser(text)` function will get the mobile number (in text) value via `ngModel` and then it `limit\trim\substring` the string\text characters up to `19 length` only.

Comment: Thanks @anoop got it !